# How to get the title of a page using httpxmlrequest

Tags: asynchronous, asp-classic, vbscript

Is it possible to get the title of the page using the XMLHTTP object?

```
function getTitle(url)
Dim objRequest

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
objRequest.open "GET", url , false
objRequest.Send

'getMsg = objRequest.status
'getMsg = objRequest.ResponseText

end function
```

I tried `objRequest.title` which didn't work.

**UPDATE**

Tried this which - probably not fail-proof - works for now:

```
f = objRequest.ResponseText
loc = Instr(f,"<title>")
loc2= Instr(f,"</title>")
getTitle = Mid(f,loc+7,loc2-loc-7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to insert the result into a DOM in order for content to be recognized at HTML. Then you'd have to ask the DOM for the page's title.

What comes back from XHR is just a blob of text until you do something with it.